# this.innerHTML doesnt works for links?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the following value: `I want this text`.

```js
function get(v){
  alert(v);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:get(this.innerHTML);">I want this text</a>
```

I tried many combinations of this, this.innerHTML, etc.. They all return `undefined`...

Any tips?

Comment: Well damnit Keanu Reeves, it seems you can do anything, except hack the `href`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the onclick handler instead:

```js
function get(v){
  alert(v);
}
```

```html
<a onclick="get(this.innerHTML); return false" href="#">I want this text</a>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `innerText` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Basically add a click event listener on your anchor tag, then when it's clicked get the innerHTML and alert it.

```js
 document.getElementById("stuff").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let yourStuff = document.getElementById("stuff").innerHTML;
  alert(yourStuff);
 });
```

```html
<a id="stuff" href="javascript:void(0)">Your stuff</a>
```

Hope this helps!